# Generate array of dates with 1 month interval in Google Sheets

Tags: date, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, unique, array-formulas

I'm trying to generate an array of dates in Google Sheets, where I know the first date, the last one and I want the other dates to be at 1-month interval, with the date always being the last day of the month.

```
StartDate (C3) = 2019-03-31
EndDate (I3) = 2019-06-30
```

Expected outcome:

```
2019-03-31
2019-04-30
2019-05-31
2019-06-30
```

This is the code I have tried

```
=ArrayFormula(ADD(C3,row(INDIRECT("C1:C"&eomonth(I3,0)-C3))))
```

But it's returning this

```
2020-04-01
2020-04-02
2020-04-03
2020-04-04
2020-04-05
2020-04-06
2020-04-07
2020-04-08
2020-04-09
2020-04-10
2020-04-11
2020-04-12
2020-04-13
2020-04-14
2020-04-15
2020-04-16
2020-04-17
2020-04-18
2020-04-19
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TEXT(UNIQUE(EOMONTH(ROW(INDIRECT(
 DATEVALUE(C3)&":"&DATEVALUE(I3))), 0)), "yyyy-MM-dd"))
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 4):

Please try:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(EOMONTH(C3,ROW(INDIRECT("a1:a"&DATEDIF(C3,I3,"M")+2))-1))`

- `=DATEDIF(C3,I3,"M")+2` = the number of monthes between 2 dates includind these dates.
- `=ARRAYFORMULA(ROW(INDIRECT("a1:a3")))` = basic counter

Answer (score 0):

My formula comes in 3 flavors.

```
Column  Formula
C   Dates in between two dates
C   =ArrayFormula(edate(A1,sequence(datedif(A1,A2,"M"))))

D   Dates in between two dates including End_date
D   =ArrayFormula(edate(A1,sequence(datedif(A1,A2,"M")+1)))

E   Dates in between two dates including Start_date and End_date
E   =ArrayFormula(edate(A1,sequence(datedif(A1,A2,"M")+2)-1))
```

[image]

And on https://sheetaki.com/auto-populate-dates-between-two-given-dates-in-google-sheets/
there is a very easy to understand method (once you understand all the SEQUENCE parameters), but for day increments

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TO_DATE(SEQUENCE(B1- A1 +1,1,A1)))
```

[image]

Auto-Populate Dates Between Two Given Dates in Google Sheets

Auto-Generate Dates Between Two Given Dates in Google Sheets

google sheets generate | populate a line for each month between two dates